# Ширина изображения больше чем у контейнера

Tags: html, css, canvas, адаптивная-верстка, позиционирование

У меня есть следующая html-разметка:

```
    <section class="editor__content editor-content">
        <button class="editor-content__scroll editor-content__scroll_prev"></button>
        <section class="editor-content__wrapper">
            <article class="edit-block">
                <div class="edit-block__wrapper">
                    <canvas width="844" height="1200" class="edit-block__image"></canvas>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="edit-block">
                <div class="edit-block__wrapper">
                    <canvas width="844" height="1200" class="edit-block__image"></canvas>
                </div>
            </article>
            <!-- Еще edit-blockи -->
        </section>
        <button class="editor-content__scroll editor-content__scroll_next"></button>
    </section>
```

И css:

```
body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
}

.editor-content {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: var(--color-background-3);
}

.editor-content__scroll {
    flex: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #111;
    z-index: 9;
    transition: .7s background-color;
}
.editor-content__scroll:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.editor-content__scroll:before {
    font: 900 40px "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    content: "\f104";
}

.editor-content__scroll_prev {
    left: 0;
}
.editor-content__scroll_next {
    right: 0;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.editor-content__wrapper {
    flex: auto;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.edit-block {
    flex: none;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.edit-block__wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: none;
}

.edit-block__text,
.edit-block__draw {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Если max-width: 100% для всех элементов, то canvas имеет 100% ширины родителя, и высоту, зависящую от своего соотношения сторон. Но почему-то если задать max-width: none элементу edit-block__wrapper, ничего не изменится, а если задать то же свойство canvas, то он выйдет за границы родителя. А мне нужно, чтобы edit-block__wrapper имел те же размеры, что и canvas. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто задать display: inline-block элементу edit-block__wrapper, также убрав у него и у canvas max-width. Дело в том, что по умолчанию у него dipslay: block, а блочные элементы, как правило, занимают ровно 100% ширины родителя. Естественно, это не будет работать, если задать родителю display, отличный от block / inline-block.